# Split output from subprocess into List or Tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file list formatted as

```py
[
    '1582120598 672 /Users/user/Desktop/',
    '1581847900 64 /Users/user/Desktop//untitled folder',
    '1581842714 352 /Users/user/Desktop//RECEIPTS',
    '1581686620 433097 /Users/user/Desktop//RECEIPTS/cameringo_20200214_132341.jpg'
]
```

I want to split each entry up into `list` (or tuple if that would be better). I'm currently using this:

```py
new_list = list(map(lambda x: re.findall('(\d+)\s(\d+)\s(.*)',str(x)), copy_list))
```

but the output is returned as a `tuple` wrapped in a `list` ie. the first entry is `[('1582120598, 672, /Users/user/Desktop/')]` and so `new_list[0][0]` is failing whereas I want it to return `1582120598`

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- map those list of tuple to list.

```
import re

copy_list = ['1582120598 672 /Users/user/Desktop/', '1581847900 64 /Users/user/Desktop//untitled folder', '1581842714 352 /Users/user/Desktop//RECEIPTS', '1581686620 433097 /Users/user/Desktop//RECEIPTS/cameringo_20200214_132341.jpg']

new_list = list(map(lambda x: re.findall('(\d+)\s(\d+)\s(.*)',str(x)), copy_list))
new_list = [list(x[0]) for x in new_list]
print(new_list)
print(new_list[0][0])
```

Output:

```
[['1582120598', '672', '/Users/user/Desktop/'],
 ['1581847900', '64', '/Users/user/Desktop//untitled folder'],
 ['1581842714', '352', '/Users/user/Desktop//RECEIPTS'],
 ['1581686620',
  '433097',
  '/Users/user/Desktop//RECEIPTS/cameringo_20200214_132341.jpg']]
'1582120598'
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you need the other groups? It seems like for your specific use-case, you could vastly simplify your lambda by splitting the string on whitespace instead of using regex:

```
>>> new_list = [
...     '1582120598 672 /Users/user/Desktop/',
...     '1581847900 64 /Users/user/Desktop//untitled folder',
...     '1581842714 352 /Users/user/Desktop//RECEIPTS',
...     '1581686620 433097 /Users/user/Desktop//RECEIPTS/cameringo_20200214_132341.jpg'
... ]
>>> first_fields = [y.split()[0] for y in new_list]
['1582120598', '1581847900', '1581842714', '1581686620']
>>> first_fields[0]
'1582120598'
```

Otherwise, if you need the other groups too:

```
>>> new_list = list(map(lambda x: re.findall('(\d+)\s(\d+)\s(.*)',str(x)), copy_list))
>>> first_fields = [x[0][0] for x in new_list]
['1582120598', '1581847900', '1581842714', '1581686620']
>>> first_fields[0]
'1582120598'
```

*An aside*:

You can simplify your `new_list` creation as follows using a list comprehension:

```
new_list = [re.findall('(\d+)\s(\d+)\s(.*)',str(x)) for x in copy_list]
```

Comment: I do need the other groups unfortunately and splitting at whitespace would not allow for whitespace in the paths. Thanks for the simplify though. Wasn't aware you could do that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do this:

```
my_list = [
    '1582120598 672 /Users/user/Desktop/', 
    '1581847900 64 /Users/user/Desktop//untitled folder',
    '1581842714 352 /Users/user/Desktop//RECEIPTS',
    '1581686620 433097 /Users/user/Desktop//RECEIPTS/cameringo_20200214_132341.jpg'
]

my_new_list = [x.split(' ') for x in my_list]
```

Then this:

```
my_new_list[0][0]
```

Returns:

```
'1582120598'
```

Comment: Thanks. Only issue with this though is if the path contains a whitespace that also gets split.